# Are there better user User management applications for Cognito User Pools?

Tags: amazon-cognito

We are using Cognito for managing the users for our saas-application (www.contempus.be) , and are very happy with the functionality it offers.
However, there are a few aspects that we think could be better, and we're wondering if there are any tools out there that can be used to easily manage users.
Do any third party tools exist to manage Cognito User Pools?

A few features we think would be useful :

- Assign groups when creating users.
- Set Custom attributes when creating users.
- Search users by custom attributes

Are other people also interested in these features?

Thank You,

Dries